# HTTPS Apache2 Information Leakage

Tags: tls, http, configuration, apache

Hello IT Security!

I have Apache2 vhost with HTTPS listening on port 443, ie. https:// securesecret.com.
I have another vhosts with HTTP listening on port 80, ie. http:// one.com, http:// two.com.

When I visited website http:// securesecret.com:443 I got this message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
<blockquote>Hint: <a href="https://securesecret.com/"><b>https://securesecret.com/</b></a></blockquote></p>
</body></html>
```

There is information about domain. How can I prevent to show it?
Where is appropriate configuration in apache?
I have disabled ServerToken, ServerSignature etc.

Comment: I noticed that information about described error (https://securesecret.com) are retrieved from first (default) vhost configuration listening on that (443) port. I can add fake vhost to obscure these information but I think this is very inelegant.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot really hide the domain name, because if someone connects to the port 443 of your server and begins initiating a SSL connection, your server will respond by sending his certificate... which contains the server name.

Actually, the client may send the intended client name as part of a [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is a rather recent extension which is not supported everywhere (Internet Explorer on Windows XP will not send it, it requires IE 8 *and* Vista or later). The server may theoretically wait for an explicit SNI before sending his certificate; however, both the SNI and the certificate will travel unencrypted at this point, so the server name cannot be considered as really secret. And you cannot realistically mandate a SNI from clients right now (maybe in five years, when the current crop of WinXP has mostly died out...).

Also, the server name is part of the data which the DNS sends to whoever asks, on a regular basis, and without any encryption. A server name is definitely not a secret.

Comment: Thanks for professional help. I know that domain name is not a secret, but it can be part of (ugly ;) ) security through obscurity. I only do not want that user of one domain get information about another domain hosted in the same IP address (reverse IP scanners etc.)

Answer (score 7):

The message you are seeing is from the default apache "400 error page". You can override the [400 error page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) via:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error-docs/400.shtml
```

in the appropriate location in your config file. Replace the default text with a generic message that doesn't include the host name.

Comment: Even if I get a proper 400 doc, I'll still get a cert that is signed for securesecret.com.

Comment: @StrangeWill: While I agree with the principle of what you're saying ("there's no way to keep the server name a secret"), the OP is doing an `http` request to port 443. The server won't send back a cert, just an error page. Try doing `echo 'GET / HTTP/1.0' | nc -q 10 secure.example.com 443`.

Comment: Ah good catch, yeah, no cert for you in that case.

Answer (score 2):

**Complete Answer:**

While the other two answers are good, this is the way you can actually solve the problem.

To get around the problems of dual homing identified by [@bstpierre](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/2980/bstpierre) and [@Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) you can use an extra IP address and separate Apache configs.

You can launch a separate Apache instance on the secure IP address to host the securesecret domain (both http and https) and the one and two domains will operate on the other Apache instance and IP addresses just using http.

Of course, you might have difficulty getting the new IP address from your provider and routing and configuring your server, but you need to determine the cost/benefit for yourself.

The [Apache config docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) have a lot of information on the scenarios and options.

**Alternative:**

- You could choose to serve the securesecret content from the other content by hosting it on a different Apache instance and a different port than usual. i.e. https://securesecret.com:444/.